# Open LocalHost From connected Client of own Hotspot

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-server, localhost, file-transfer

First of all sorry for my English,
I am planning to built a application that can **transfer file By Wi-Fi** .For this i make a simple HTTP server and made "E:\trasferfle" folder as Root of Localhost and place a HTML file their and open it on Browser by address Localhost ,which open a index.HTML file on the Root folder.

Then i want to open this file from another computer.for this
i use command

***netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="Bipashant" key="123123123" KeyUsage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork***

to create Hotspot,that make me a server and other as client.
and then another PC is connected on this wi-fi,but when i type Localhost on the another PC,it does not do any thing,

how can i open this file on that PC.

Any suggestion will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 192.168.137.1 ip address instead of localhost. Localhost is only loop back to your own computer (interface of your computer) and is also represented by ip address 127.0.0.1.